# Colaboratory Login with Kids account

Tags: google-colaboratory

My daughter has a KIDS gmail account she is 10.  She is taking a class using Colaboratory.  Colaboratory will not let her login with her GMAIL account.  Does anyone know why?

-Otis

Answer (score 1):

Colab doesn't support accounts for children. You'll need to use an ordinary Google account with Colab.